# providing pop-up while publishing to Web data base

Tags: publishing

We had set up an additional publishing target(pub db) apart from the Web db.

While the admin is selecting the web db and publishing, an alert need to be displayed, stating that web db is selected for Publishing. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

As stated by your question, No, not without significant programming and disabling default Sitecore screens. (You'd basically have to replace the publishing dialog with an alternate. Not impossible, but depending on whether you needed the dialog to appear in all the natural places the Sitecore one does, difficult. You'd have to use both Sheer and Speak UI paradigms to cover it.

**Other Approaches:**

There are quite a few places in Sitecore where you can control the publishing targets.

**Configuration Files**

In the sitecore.config file you can change the `DefaultPublishingTargets` setting to include only the targets that "regular" users should access, a "staging target" for example. You can then use the judicious assignment of super-users to the Sitecore Client Advanced Publishing role, which will give super-users the ability to change/add publishing targets to a specific publishing run.

**Workflow**

You can also create publishing targets that are valid for non-final workflow states, and have a publishing action assigned to a given workflow state such that an Item that is moved to that workflow state by a "regular" user is published to the correct target, and only the correct target. In this scenario, the "regular" user doesn't even need to be a member of Sitecore Client Publishing, as publishing is handled automatically.

**In Practice**

In my opinion, using Workflow to publish Items is probably ideal, however caching and the shallow publishing of related content makes this inconsistent in Sitecore *out-of-the-box*. You'll probably have to build your own Workflow Actions that do a better job of publishing the Item, related Media, any required parents, and related items to make this "usable". I'll put the usual admonition that if you don't have Workflow set up, you **absolutely should**, Sitecore *expects* there to be workflow to govern publishing.

Failing the use of workflow, restricting publishing targets to specific user groups should address your problem.  I'll warn against having content authors be *Admin*. ***Admin* is not designed to be used during content entry**, it violates and circumvents too many processes associated with the content lifecycle.

It is normal to see a blend of these two approaches. In general, I would avoid modifying the Sitecore user experience (an expensive and risky endeavor).